# Querying indexed vector layer (finding nearby point)?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatial-index

I can find nearby features in a layer by using `QgsSpatialIndex`: [Finding the nearest line to a point in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59173/how-to-find-the-nearest-line-to-a-point-in-qgis) Using this method, we need to feed in all existing features and query it with a point to get back the nearby features.

**However I wonder what is indexed vector layer**, the option that can be enabled when creating a new in-memory layer. I thought that it would perform indexing for all features and would give better performance during querying. Therefore, there must be a way to issue a nearby query on the layer itself without explicitly initialising `QgsSpatialIndex`, or else why should I turn on the index option?

I can turn on index in `Layer Properties > General > Create spatial index` or it will be turned on by default if I create a temporary scratch layer. I notice that it improves the speed of rendering.

Now in my PyQGIS script, how can I take advantage of the **existing** index without creating a `QgsSpatialIndex` class to query nearby features or doing any nearest neighbor analysis?

```
spIndex = QgsSpatialIndex()
for pointFeatures in pointsLayer.getFeatures():
    spIndex.insertFeature(pointFeat)
nearbyPointFeatureIds = spIndex.nearestNeighbor(testPoint, 3)
```

My concern is why I should create my own in-memory index again in the first three lines above. Have I missed that I can get something like a `QgsVectorLayer.spatialIndex.nearestNeighbor()` from the layer itself?

Comment: Do you have a code sample to clarify what you mean?

Comment: Do you know what is the purpose of indexing layer? You can see the example in the link.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN, was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know, you are comparing different things (even if their names are similar and this could be misleading).

---

As you correctly wrote, the [QgsSpatialIndex()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsSpatialIndex.html) class is useful for finding nearest objects. The following text is an excerpt from the [QGIS Documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#using-spatial-index) (the *[...]* and the bold style are added by me for the sake of clearness):

> Spatial indexes can dramatically improve the performance of your code
>   if you need to do frequent queries to a vector layer. [...] This can
>   be a very time consuming task, especially if it needs to be repeated
>   for several locations. If a spatial index exists for the layer, the
>   operation is much more effective.
>
> [...]
>
> Spatial indexes **are not created by default** for a QGIS vector layer,
>   but you can create them easily. This is what you have to do:
>
> - create spatial index — the following code creates an empty index
>
>   **`index = QgsSpatialIndex()`**

The `QgsSpatialIndex()` class is only used **temporarily** and improves the performance of **querying** a shapefile.

---

Instead, a **Spatial Index** improves the performance of **drawing** a shapefile and it is generally **stored on disk**. The following text is an excerpt from the [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html#improving-performance-shape) (the bold style is added by me for the sake of clearness):

> To improve the performance of drawing a shapefile, you can create a
>   spatial index. **A spatial index will improve the speed of both
>   zooming and panning**. Spatial indexes used by QGIS have a `.qix`
>   extension.
>
> Use these steps to create the index:
>
> - Load a shapefile.
> - Open the `Layer Properties` dialog by double-clicking on the shapefile name in the legend or by right-clicking and choosing
>     `Properties` from the popup menu.
> - In the tab `General` click the `[Create Spatial Index]` button.

Using PyQGIS, a spatial index would be created using the [createSpatialIndex()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a2fcb9f703debaf73667643614802d3a6) module from the [QgsVectorDataProvider](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html) class:

```
provider = layer.dataProvider()
index = provider.createSpatialIndex()
```

This will create a spatial index on the datasource and the `.qix` file in the same folder where the original shapefile is stored.

---

With these premises, I try to add something more to the answer in the case of dealing with memory layers instead of persistent shapefiles (the following needs to be intended as a personal opinion since I wasn't able to verify it).

I think that the following text, reported in the [QGIS Documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/it/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#memory-provider) (the *[...]* are added by me for the sake of clearness):

> [...]
>
> The memory provider also supports spatial indexing, which is enabled
>   by calling the provider’s `createSpatialIndex()` function. Once the
>   spatial index is created you will be able to iterate over features
>   within smaller regions faster (since it’s not necessary to traverse
>   all the features, only those in specified rectangle).
>
> A memory provider is created by passing "memory" as the provider
>   string to the QgsVectorLayer constructor.
>
> [...]
>
> The URI can also specify the coordinate reference system, fields, and
>   indexing of the memory provider in the URI. The syntax is:
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> `index=yes` (Specifies that the provider will use a spatial index)
> ```

refers to a **Spatial Index** and not to the `QgsSpatialIndex()` class, so it is only used for improving the performance of drawing the layer and this justifies why a `QgsSpatialIndex()` class is often called when a query on many features is needed.

Comment: Thanks to point out the `createSpatialIndex()` method. It indicate that **Spatial Index** do nothing in memory layer because it simply `return false`. That means actually memory layer does not support spatial index. Besides that, I can also conclude that there is no `QgsSpatialIndex()` created by memory layer or provider in order for me to just use it. So I have to create one and update whenever there are features added/removed!

Comment: I just don't understand why the documentation said "The memory provider also supports spatial indexing". I found nothing in the `QgsVectorLayer` and `QgsVectorDataProvider` source code related to it.

Comment: @CallMeLaNN I think it's related to the next sentence: _which is enabled by calling the provider’s createSpatialIndex() function_, so maybe it still refers to **Spatial Index** (and not `QgsSpatialIndex()`).

Answer (score 1):

First question is 'what format is your data stored as'?

If you are talking a PostGIS table, for example, the spatial index WILL be used by default.

Regarding other data formats, [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107594/does-qgis-automatically-use-spatialite-spatial-indexes) indicates that a spatialite spatial index is used.

> Yes. It does as it appears from looking at the source code for the Spatialite Data Provider.

And from that, I would assume that if an index exists, it'll be used. The QGIS `QgsSpatialIndex()` function is handy for use if the dataset doesn't already have an index.

Comment: It is just temporary scratch layer using in-memory data provider. I have a python script to retrieve data from MongoDb, create `QgsFeature`s and add into the layer. I just afraid if `QgsSpatialIndex` is redundant with what the index exists. So if it exists for memory layer, how to use it in python?